# Missing character: There is no ℕ in font cmss10!

Tags: fonts, unicode

How can I select and specify a font which contains the character I have in my file ?

> Missing character: There is no ℕ in font cmss10!

I can see them perfectly within emacs, but I am unable to process them with xelatex because of this error

(edit) in emacs ℕ is said to be :

```
             position: 129 of 190 (67%), column: 14
            character: ℕ (displayed as ℕ) (codepoint 8469, #o20425, #x2115)
    preferred charset: unicode (Unicode (ISO10646))
code point in charset: 0x2115
               script: symbol
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: .:Base, L:Left-to-right (strong)
             to input: type "\Bbb{N}" or "\bn" with Agda input method
          buffer code: #xE2 #x84 #x95
            file code: #xE2 #x84 #x95 (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)
              display: by this font (glyph code)
    mac-ct:-*-Arial Unicode MS-bold-normal-normal-*-12-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1 (#xD24)
```

Comment: this for the moronic silent down vote

Comment: Without any hint of how to reproduce the warning, there's not much anybody can say (I wasn't the downvoter).

Comment: The message is self explanatory :  ℕ is not in the font cmss10. I dont see why one would want to 'reproduce'. it's about selecting a font which contains the wanted character

Comment: How should we know how your document is configured? Which font is Emacs using to display it?

Comment: @daleif I guess the same as your browser..

Comment: `\usepackage{amssymb}` and `$\mathbb{N}$` does it. What's the purpose of comparing the font substitutions Emacs makes with typesetting?

Comment: @egreg the point of using unicode is that you dont have to use those encodings, and have directly the wanted character displayed. I dont understand your question about the font substitution.

Comment: @nicolas You should be using the [`unicode-math`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.pdf) package, if you want to input your math as unicode characters.

Comment: The question is why your document is trying to use cmss10 to typeset your char. So make a complete example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cmss10` is not a Unicode font unfortunately - you need to use a font which implements Unicode maths - the TeX Gyre collection is probably a good starting point.  Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\begin{document}
Some Unicode maths: $x ∈ ℕ$
\end{document}
```

Process with `xelatex` or `lualatex` to produce this:

[image]

You may need to install the [TeX Gyre fonts](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/).

Some other compatible fonts are listed on the [Github page for unicode-math](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math) but the list there is slightly out of date.  The Tex Gyre project also maintains [a list of suitable maths fonts](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tg-math).

Comment: for reference : http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/  although it feels like fishing