# Missing character:There is no │ (U+2502) in font (xelatex)

Tags: xetex, unicode, pandoc

Packages I am loading:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
   twoside
  ,bindingoffset=1cm
  ,top=1.5cm
  ,bottom=0.5cm
  ,left=0.9cm
  ,right=0.6cm
  ,asymmetric
}

%% Leave me LAST!
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=black
}
```

My setting: I download some data from the web which contains html-formatted chunks (e.g. `give me &pound;12 and 1 &le; x!` etc.), then I pass this through `pandoc` to convert the same chunk in `latex`. I place those `latex` chunks inside my `latex` template and run `xelatex` on it. Just to be clear: the template is mine, `pandoc` only converts some chunks of html to latex, it does not produce the whole latex document.

The html's `&pound;` are converted by `pandoc` to unicode chars which `xelatex` can deal with (I would prefered to have them all as tex-math symbols as i am really annoyed with littering my source documents with unicode except "foreign" languages).

The problem with above setting is that unicode chars like `≤  (U+2264)`, and `| (U+2502)` are not found by `xelatex`. I have managed to load different fonts (as per [Missing character: There is no ℕ in font cmss10!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306211/missing-character-there-is-no-%e2%84%95-in-font-cmss10) , my packages are shown at the beginning of this post) and **now `xelatex` recognises most of these unicode chars except | (U+2502)**.
I get:

```
Missing character: There is no │ (U+2502) in font TeX Gyre Schola/OT:script=lat
n;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
```

**Update**: The above problem has been solved thanks to the comments I got. But I have now same problem with different character. Here is the script:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
%\newunicodechar{^^^^1D45A}{a} % this does not recognise hex

\begin{document}
this -1 should read $m-1$
\end{document}
```

m is not rendered with this error in log:

```
Missing character: There is no  (U+1D45A) in font TeX Gyre Schola/OT:script=la
```

But that font is there.

**Update**: this has now been solved (thanks @David Carlisle):

Is there a font which supports this char?

**Update**: this has now been solved, Yes use `albatross`!!!! (which is great, thanks @Ulrike Fischer):

Is there a place where I can enter the unicode char and find a tex font which supports it?

Comment: you can use on the command line albatross: `albatross U+2502` will output a list of fonts on your system. see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/627471/2388. Side remark: xltxtra is mostly obsolete and textcomp is in the kernel now.

Comment: 2502 is a box drawing character, are you sure you want that, and not | (U+007C) or ∣  (U+2223)

Comment: don't use `\usepackage{textcomp}` with xelatex (or even with pdflatex with current releases) avoid `\usepackage{xltxtra}` as well, just use `\usepackage{fontspec}`

Comment: `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}`  all these are resetting everything, only the last one is having any effect

Comment: as your text font is `TeX Gyre Schola` you should probably have `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}` not `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}`

Comment: `this does not recognise hex`   you have invalid syntax, `^^^^` requires lowercase hex, you could also use `\newunicodechar{}{m}`

Comment: I have deleted my previous comment that ```\newunicodechar{}{m}``` did not work, I stupidly missed ```\usepackage{newunicodechar}```. So it DOES work. But this doesnt (so as not pollute my document with all these unicodes): ```\newunicodechar{^^^^1d454}{a}```

Comment: @bliako If the code is five hex digit long, you need five `^`.

Comment: @egreg +!!!! At some stage I was giving it three ```^```.

Answer (score 4):

The TeX Gyre Math fonts you are using do have U+2502

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
% only if you need it \usepackage{ucharclasses}
% not with xetex \usepackage{textcomp}
% avoid, better to just use fontspc, already included by unicode-math \usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
% this over-writes the prevous setting \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
% this over-writes the prevous setting \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
% this over-writes the prevous setting \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
% this over-writes the prevous setting \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}



\begin{document}

abc $x\mid y$ $x ^^^^2502 y$  [^^^^2502] [|]

\end{document}
```

U+2502 is a box drawing character which really has no place in text and should probably just be replaced with | but the text used above produces

```
Missing character: There is no │ (U+2502) in font TeX Gyre Schola/OT:script=lat
n;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
```

If you can not fix the source not to use it, you could remap it using character classes,or more simply with `newunicodechar`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
% only if you need it \usepackage{ucharclasses}
% not with xetex \usepackage{textcomp}
% avoid, better to just use fontspc, already included by unicode-math \usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
% this over-writes the prevous setting \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
% this over-writes the prevous setting \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
% this over-writes the prevous setting \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
% this over-writes the prevous setting \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{^^^^2502}{|}

\begin{document}

abc $x\mid y$ $x ^^^^2502 y$  [^^^^2502] [|]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this which fixed the problem. However now a new problem arose: ```Missing character: There is no  (U+1D45A) in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=``` but ```albatross``` told me that  ```TeX Gyre Schola Math``` must have it. My source has ```\usepackage{unicode-math}\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}```. And also ```\newunicodechar{^^^^1D45A}{m}``` fails with ```Text line contains an invalid character.``` I have updated my original post above to include the minimum script to reproduce. Thanks again.

Comment: all math fonts will have it but why are you setting a math italic m in latin moder _text_ ? ad why use TeX Gyre Schola Math with latin moder (your example here used TeX Gyre Schola for text. @bliako

Comment: You have not updated the question @bliako

Comment: just now!  thanks. I have no control over the source. The source is supposed to be html but there are interspersed unicode characters like this fancy m. I can filter the source but there will be no end to this. People using a word processor to produce html or even email  client will always pollute with this unicodes that said software is happy to provide. I am puzzled as to why my minimal script does not work but also ```\newunicodechar``` seems to break with U+1D45A